# why isAlive() method of Thread instance is giving wrong result?

Tags: java, multithreading, join, interrupt

I came to know that below code gives the output as false , but when we see this Thread instance , thread , which we created is set as daemon and is still running then why the method call thread.isAlive() , is returning false , giving wrong impression that "thread is completed the work and is dead "

```
public class MyThreads {

    private static class MyDaemonThread extends Thread {

        public MyDaemonThread() {
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new MyDaemonThread();
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
    }
}
```

can any one have idea on this ?

Comment: It doesn't display false? Because `join()` will wait for the thread to finish. Also it doesn't matter whether the thread is a daemon or not in this example.

Comment: The last line will not be called untill thread is finished due to use of `thread.join();` that will join `main` thread to wait till its end.

Comment: _giving wrong impression that "thread is completed the work and is dead_ In fact it is. `join()` makes the program wait for the thread to finish, so when you print `thread.isAlive()`, the thread will be dead.

Comment: HI all for those who saying that , programme will not print  false or programme will not execute the , System.out.println(thread.isAlive());  Please try to execute it , i executed the programe before asking for help on that , i even now also executed it still it is giving output as false only .

Answer (score 4):

`thread.join();` is an expression that tells the main thread to wait for `thread` termination. so, it only goes to the printing statement when the thread has finished. so its the right result, because `thread` already terminated.

if you remove the `join`, you will see the result is true

Comment: Hi Dima , but the last line , "thread.isAlive()"  is to check whether the thread is alive or not , whether join call present or not this print statement must print true . but it is printing false only . without join means , that print statement be still executed by main thread as for the main thread no need to wait , so my doubt is with or without join() , it should always print true only . for the Daemon thread which i mentioned .

Comment: as i said, join is literally waiting for the thread to terminate, so it will never be alive after it